# Django Pagination for Component

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having trouble getting pagination to work on a component template with a has-many relationship where we have a view for ModelA which has a component template for ModelB, but ModelB does not have its own url.

I'm guessing that I have an error in the views.py but I'm not really sure what else I should put to get pagination working for ModelB. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! I can also put up more code on request.

Views:

```
ModelAView(ListView):
   model: ModelA
   template_name = 'modela.html'

# Model A has-many Model B
ModelBView(ListView):
   model: ModelB
   template_name = 'modelb.html'
   # this paginate is not working
   paginate_by = 10
```

template for modela.html:

```
{% for a in object_list %}
{% include 'modelb.html' with modela=modela %}
{% endfor %}
```

template for modelb.html:

```
{% for modelb in modela.modelb.all%}
# this is displayed in a table format but not being paginated.
...
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^modela/$', ModelA.as_view(), name='model-a')
```

Comment: The fact that there is a `ListView` with `modelB` does not change anything with how the `{% include 'modelb.html' %}` renders the related objects. It just gets a queryset, and renders that queryset, that's all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in this case, how do I pass in a queryset of modelB that will allow pagination to happen? I assume I should add a `get_queryset()` function to my modelB classview?

Comment: no, since *again* the fact that there is another `ListView` that somehow deals with `ModelB`, and somehow renders to the same template does not matter. Each view can render zero, one, or multiple templates, and each template can be rendered by zero, one or more views. So one view is "oblivious" to the fact that there are other views. So changing the logic of another view has no effect on that view.